# unable to get the correct output from my codeigniter query code

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am executing output from the below code. But i am getting one data lesser.Is my below code is wrong?
Same query with correct variable i executed into **my sql query brower i am getting 6 results**. But from my ****below code i am getting only 5 results****.
What could be the reason behind this magic?

```
 public function get_all_book_list_ByCreatedDateDSC($limit, $start,$sortsesval)
    {
     $id=0; 
     $this->load->helper('date'); 
     $datestring = "%Y-%m-%d: %d:%h:%i";
     $time = time(); 
     $today=mdate($datestring, $time); 
     $pasttime=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-7 days"));
     printf('$today='.$today);  printf('$pasttime='.$pasttime);

     $this->load->database();  
     $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
     $this->db->select('*'); 
     $query =$this->db->join('coverdetails', 'coverdetails.cover_id = bookdetails.cover_id')->where('quantity >', $id)->where("bookdetails.created_date BETWEEN '$pasttime' AND '$today'")->get('bookdetails');
     print_r('no or rows='.$query->num_rows() );//output no or rows=5

      if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    return false;
   }
```

Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you function code like this

```
public function get_all_book_list_ByCreatedDateDSC($limit, $start,$sortsesval)
{
    $this->load->helper('date'); 
    $this->load->database();  

    $id         =   0; 
    $datestring =   "%Y-%m-%d: %d:%h:%i";
    $time       =   time(); 
    $today      =   mdate($datestring, $time); 
    $pasttime   =   date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-7 days"));



    return $this->db
                ->select('*'); 
                ->join('coverdetails', 'coverdetails.cover_id = bookdetails.cover_id')
                ->where('quantity >', $id)
                ->where("bookdetails.created_date BETWEEN '$pasttime' AND '$today'")
                ->limit($limit, $start)
                ->get('bookdetails');
                ->result_array();
}
```

Also for testing use `$this->db->last_query()` and copy the query than paste it in PHP MyAdmin to test. Other possibilities are `$limit` and `$offset` and `Between` that may cause the change in number of records.

Comment: Thanks. Problem was that my  `$start` limit was wrong. Intially i was sending `1` thats why i was getting one result less. I learn new thing `$this->db->last_query()` ,which will help me in future alot

Comment: You are Welcome! Read [Codeigntier User Guide Database Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html). This will help you a lot.